# Compile ROS Groovy on Beagleboard?

Tags: ros, beagleboard, ros-groovy, groovy-beta

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Dear ROS Community,

Our engineering team is seeking the possibilities of compiling ROS Groovy on a Beagleboard, which will have OpenSuse installed.  We are wondering if there are any known difficulties of this Groovy + OpenSuse + Beagleboard combination?

Also, would you suggest us to directly compile ROS from source on Beagleboard, or cross-compile it?

Thank you!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/50434/compile-ros-groovy-on-beagleboard?/) by [Derek Chiang](https://answers.ros.org/users/3787/derek-chiang/) on ROS Answers with karma: 21 on 2012-12-13

Post score: 2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

It is easiest to compile directly on beagle board ... however, that will take a while. I have had success with compiling ROS with [distcc](http://code.google.com/p/distcc/) for raspberry pi. It really helps speed things up.

---

Originally posted by [Kevin](https://answers.ros.org/users/186/kevin/) with karma: 2962 on 2012-12-15

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I just made a blog post with step-by-step instructions for compiling ROS Groovy on the BeagleBoard-xM with Ubuntu. Not sure about OpenSuSE, though. However, I don't have the karma to post links. Google Sysadmin Fixes and look for the post ROS on Beaglebuntu.

If you're looking for the original BeagleBoard, these instructions won't be exactly the same.

---

Originally posted by [Josh Whitley](https://answers.ros.org/users/4390/josh-whitley/) with karma: 1766 on 2013-04-28

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Kevin](https://answers.ros.org/users/186/kevin/) on 2013-04-28**:
Here is the [link](http://sysadminfixes.wordpress.com/2013/03/18/ros-on-beaglebuntu/)

**Comment by [Josh Whitley](https://answers.ros.org/users/4390/josh-whitley/) on 2013-04-29**:
Thanks for posting the link!